# *Why* is "I've been to <place>" grammatically valid only in perfect constructions?

Tags: idioms, perfect-aspect

While riding my bike this morning, my mind was wandering. All of a sudden I realized that the phrase "I've been to (place)" is very strange because if you change the aspect of the verb, it is no longer grammatically valid. You can say "I've been to Chicago" but not "I am to Chicago" or "I will be to Chicago." But other tenses work as long as it's perfect aspect: "I will have been to Chicago," "I hadn't been to Chicago."

There is [at least one question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84365/usage-of-been-to-in-perfect-tenses-and-in-other-tenses) about this already. But I was wondering **why** is this the case? Is there any historical or etymological explanation for why this idiom has such strange behavior? Relatedly, are there any other phrases in English that work this way, or parallel idioms in other languages?

Comment: If you conjugate the verbs 'have', 'be' and 'go' where is there room for doubt?

How is 'I've been…' comparable to 'I will be…' let alone to 'I am…'?

Comment: While riding my bike this morning, my mind was wandering. Technically, my mind was not riding the bike, so ... maybe: While riding my bike this morning, **I noticed** my mind was wandering.

Comment: "I am to Chicago" is good Shakespearean English.  KING: "Thus set it down: he shall with speed to England."  _Hamlet_, Act 3, Scene 1.

Comment: And for me it does have a future (with *will*) and a simple past as well. See my answer for examples.

Comment: For pete's sake: I am in Chicago. **Don't confuse *go to* and be in**.  I don't get why the honchos don't point out this simple fact. {Forget Shakespeare for a minute)

Answer (score 4):

The reason is that there's two meanings of the verb *go* in English. There's the go and come back meaning (*I go to school every day*), and there's the leave/go to meaning (*She just upped and went* or *She went to Australia for good*).

English has two past participles for the verb *go*, both of them are suppletive, and they mean slightly different things. One of them is the word *gone* which means "travelled away from here" or "travelled to", the other is *been* which means something like "travelled to and returned from."

So if you go to your friend's house and their mum answers the door and says: "Oh, she's gone to France", it means she's still there. But if the mum answers and says "Oh, she's been to France", she's probably upstairs sleeping or something. She's back at any rate.

The past participle of the verb *be* and this particular past participle of the verb *go* are identical, of course. That also happens in other languages too. But the reason that *been* takes a *to*-preposition phrase sometimes is basically that, in such cases, it's the verb *go* and not the verb *be*.

Comment: Aha this really makes it click for me! I will wait to see if anyone has any major objections before accepting

Comment: A statement like 'English has two past participles for the verb go' needs endorsement.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Here's one: ["Kids Box American English Level 6 Student's book"](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Kid_s_Box_American_English_Level_6_Stude/s6eV7PfiQYoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22go/went/been%22&pg=PA11&printsec=frontcover) "*Go went been/gone*"

Comment: Another smoking gun: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/grammar/online-grammar/present-perfect-simple-been-and-gone

Comment: @eltomito Nice one. A gun with pedigree. Edwin Ashworth would approve!

Comment: I always supported Cambridge on the river. However, I think seeing 'been' as a true past participle of 'go' is a peripheral stance. 'Have been [to]' is usually treated as an idiom, a relatively fixed phrase ('have' inflects) synonymous with 'visited'. 'Gone' is obviously morphologically related to 'go' and is unquestionably a past participle; 'been' relates to 'be'.

Comment: @Araucaria-Him I upvoted your answer before but I think I found something that might interest you. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Present Perfect construction, as you have seen, has a number of uses. These were cataloged in a [famous article by James D. McCawley](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63263/15299).

Here they are. The example sentence falls under category (b):

- (a) The **Universal** sense of the Perfect, used to indicate that a state of affairs prevailed throughout some interval stretching from the past into the present
  • *I've known Max since 1960.*
- (b) The **Existential** sense of the Perfect, used to indicate the existence of past events,
  • *I have read* Principia Mathematica *five times.*
- (c) The **Stative/Resultative** sense of the Perfect,
  used to indicate that the direct effect of a past event still continues
  • *I can't come to your party tonight - I've caught the flu.*
- (d) The **Hot News** sense of the Perfect, used to report hot news
  • *Malcolm X has just been assassinated.*

As to **why** it requires the present perfect construction ("present" is a tense, btw -- the only other tense in English is "past" -- while "perfect" is a construction, not a suffix on a verb.)  *Be to* `placename` is an idiom meaning 'travel to (and leave again)'. So *I've been to Portland 5 times* means I'm reporting the existence of least one punctual event in the past. That's the point of the Existential sense. It's just like the Universal sense, but it's not a permanent state like the Universal; rather, it's an event, or a series of them.

Comment: Curiously, the exceptions to the present perfect rules (more common in AmE) don't seem to apply here: "I already went to the store" is fine, but \*"I already was to the store" isn't.

Comment: I think that's evidence that _be to_ Placename is an idiom, with its own meaning and provenance. And rules. That's pretty much true of anything starting with _be_, since it's always an auxiliary, even if it isn't obvious what it's auxing -- in this case, the idiom construction.

Comment: I still don't quite see from this answer why, if "be to (placename)" is an idiom, it requires the perfect construction, whether past perfect, present perfect, or future perfect.

Comment: Because that is one of the idiomatic constraints that make it an idiom. There isn't any _why?_ any  more than there's a _why?_ to using _to_ to mark infinitives; that's just the arbitrary rule. But this is not a general rule; this is an idiomatic rule.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there's a phrasal verb **be to** (a place) and that it lost its  present-with-future-meaning usage somewhere along the way:

> *I am to London.

but it does retain a future usage:

> I'll be t' Chicago this spring. We can meet then.

and it does retain its past tense usage:

> I was to London on business. Don't you remember?
>
> When were you to Ireland? I've got family there.

and its perfect usages:

> I have been to London.
>
> Before moving to London permanently, I had been to London only once.

All of those retained usages are idiomatic for me, American English, mid-Atlantic dialect.

Comment: This would be far more convincing with cited examples of the 'past tense' and 'future' usage. E.g. [_For a few years she **was to London** with her economist husband Parakala Prabhakar, where she worked with PricewaterhouseCoopers as a researcher and even did a stint in BBC_](https://www.rediff.com/news/report/bjp-may-nominate-nirmala-sitharaman-to-rajya-sabha-from-gujarat/20110704.htm). 'Because I said so' just doesn't cut it.

Comment: @DW256 Yeah, feel free not to be convinced.  Not everything that is spoken gets written down on the internet or in a book that gets scanned by google.  I don't find that attestation to be using the locution in the same way it's used around here. "For a few years...." is not the context where it would be used here, and that strikes my ear as ungrammatical.  Here it refers to a visit there and back, not to a stay.

Comment: Exactly my point. Cited examples with context are important or else anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Modern grammar would say that the ***been*** in *I have been to Chicago* is a ***motional be*** i.e., a motional sense in construction with the perfect (as opposed to other uses such as *copula be*, *progressive be*...) Since its ***motional***, it takes a ***to (place)***.  We know it is restricted to the perfect as shown in the ungrammaticality of *I was to Chicago.*

I acknowledged that other grammar sources would say that the ***been*** is another form of ***go*** verb but I prefer the **motional be** analysis since it nicely accounts for the difference in meaning between **has been** and **has gone**( We are dealing with two different verbs). And we don't have a problem when we convert **has gone** to its past form in the sentence ***I went to Chicago*** since **go** is unquestionably a verb of motion.

Lastly, another user already noted that morphologically speaking, *gone* is related to *go* as is *been* to *be*. I think that counts for the *motional be* analysis.

Comment: This is one of the standard views of the status of the word *been* in *I've been to Paris* etc. However, it's got tonnes of problems. Not least that it cannot answer the question here! (Your answer doesn't begin to answer the OP's question here  - or try to). Why does this meaning of the verb *be* only apply in the present perfect? Why does the verb *be* suddenly appear in idioms with the verb *go*, but only in the present perfect? Why does the verb *be* not have the go and return meaning in any other construction? etc, etc, etc

Comment: @Araucaria-Him. You are right. I forgot to note in my answer that it didn't address the specific question of the OP.  My answer is only reporting that "been" is the motional be in other analysis.